# $n$ last digits of the sum $i^i$

Tags: number-theory

I'm searching way to designate the last $n$ digits of the sum $i^i$.

I using this http://oeis.org/A001923/b001923.txt

And I noticed one fact.

The nine and ten words have identical digits, for example:

9 *405071317*

10 10*405071317*

19 2018*612200059554303215024*

20 1068762*12200059554303215024*

How can I find similar dependencies?

Comment: The difference between the 9th and 10th terms is $10^{10}$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $10^{10}$, $20^{20}$, and more generally $10k^{10k}$ are numbers which end in a *lot* of zeroes ($10k$ to be precise). So it makes sense that if you add them to the previous sum, some of the last digits are identical.

Comment: basically I want to designate n-last digits, but this numbers are too big

Comment: This relationship happens only on multiples of 10; otherwise, you won't find anything 'interesting'.

Comment: I'm grateful for your help